# scala regex replace not working with multiple patterns and for capital newline

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string and replace regex pattern like the following:

```
//1 - var x = "ffw\nw\naa\\N".replaceAll("[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t\\n]", "")
//2 - var x = "ffw\nw\naa\\N".replaceAll("[\\n]", "")
print(x)
```

1) Does not cleanse anything, although this is the pattern I want to use.

2) Only cleanses lowercase newlines.  If I attempt to do `var x = "ffw\nw\naa\\N".replaceAll("[\\N]", "")` to cleanse capital N new lines, I get this error 
`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 2`

```
[\N]
  ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1957)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Pattern.java:2473)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2635)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2564)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2065)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1998)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1698)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
```

`[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t\\n]` This is the regex pattern I would like to use, however it is not working and it does not cleanse capital N new lines.

Comment: Do you want to remove combinations of ``\`` and `N`? Like `"""[^\u0020-\u00FF\u0001\t\n]|\\N"""` (equal to `"[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t\\n]|\\\\N"`)?

Comment: `"""[^\u0020-\u00FF\u0001\t\n]|\\N"""` this works it correctly removes `\n` and `\N` character, however I would prefer a single double quote method.  But `"[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t\\n]|\\\\N"` removes `\N` but not `\n` characters.

Comment: `val x = "ffw\nw\naa\\N".replaceAll("[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t\\n]|\\\\N", "")` then `print(x)` no `\N` but has `\n` characters

Comment: If you need to remove newlines, why use `\n` at all in the negated character class? Use `"[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t]|\\\\N"`. See https://ideone.com/nv20LN that yields `ffwwaa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
val s = "ffw\nw\naa\\N"
val rx = "\\\\N|[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t]"
println(s.replaceAll(rx, ""))
// => ffwwaa
```

See the [online Scala demo](https://ideone.com/nv20LN).

**Details**

- `[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t]` - a negated character class that matches any char BUT the chars from the `\u0020-\u00FF` range, `\u0001` and a tab
- `|` - or
- `\\\\N` - a backslash + `N` char combination.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DK9UJ/1).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this with Regex?

This works (at least for your example:

```
val y = "ffw\nw\naa\\N".replace("\\N", "\\n")
```

Comment: I can't have multiple replaces done, I need to edit `[^\\u0020-\\u00FF\\u0001\\t\\n]` to account for capital N new line characters, and don't know why that does not handle normal new lines characters.  I am using regex because that is the requirement I am working with, we are dealing with a parameterizable regex string.  The exact string was working in our old workflow, don't understand why it will not work with scala.